# Batch command with three items from textfile

Tags: c#, linq

I have a textfile, like this:

```
Tokyo 
Japan
8797987
Amsterdam
Nederland
88788787
Den Haag 
Nederland      
787875454
Madrid
Spain
7877878
```

So in the batch there are three items: 
Capital
Country
Population

and I am using the command Batch from MoreLinq.

I know to do it with a dictionary.

But how to manage this with three items for every batch?

What I mean with that is that for example you are searching for a capital and country that you will returned the capital + the country + the population

I try it like this:

```
public interface IDatabase
    {

        int GetPopulation(string name);

    }

    public class SingleTOnDatabase : IDatabase
    {

        private System.Collections.Generic.List capitols;

        private SingleTOnDatabase()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing database");

            capitols = File.ReadAllLines("Capitols.txt")
               .Batch(3)
                .ToList(
                list => list.ElementAt(0).Trim(),
                list => list.ElementAt(1).Trim(),
                list => int.Parse((list.ElementAt(2)))
                );
        }

        public int GetPopulation(string name)
        {

            return capitols[name];

        }

        private static Lazy<SingleTOnDatabase> instance = new Lazy<SingleTOnDatabase>(() => new SingleTOnDatabase());
        public static SingleTOnDatabase Instance => instance.Value;

    }
    public class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var db = SingleTOnDatabase.Instance;
        var city = "Den Haag";
        var Country = "Nederland";
        Console.WriteLine($"{Country} with {city} has population of: {db.GetPopulation(city)}");
        Console.Read();


    }
    }
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what this mean `But how to manage this with three items for every batch?`

Comment: I have updated the post. Hopefully it makes now more clear what I mean with that

Comment: means if i search any record with `country` or `capitol` then it will returns your output as `capitol + the country + the population` right?

Comment: yes, from the texfile. If if where just two items then you can use a Dictionary. But with three items that is of course not possible. So can you still use the command Batch for it with three items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never try to use text files as databases (if this is a serious job, for hobby projects who cares).

I revised your "batch" plus GetPopulation (and also added GetCapitol):

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    int? GetPopulation(string name);
    Capitol GetCapitol(string name);
}

public class Capitol
{ 
    public string CapitolName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int? Population { get; set; }
}

public class SingleTOnDatabase : IDatabase
{

    private System.Collections.Generic.List<Capitol> capitols;

    private SingleTOnDatabase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing database");

        int pop;
        capitols = (from batch in File.ReadAllLines("Capitols.txt").Batch(3)
                       let bArr = batch.ToArray()
                       where bArr.Length == 3
                       select new Capitol
                       {
                           CapitolName = bArr[0].Trim(),
                           Country = bArr[1].Trim(),
                           Population = int.TryParse(bArr[2], out pop) ? pop : (int?)null
                       }).ToList();
    }


    public int? GetPopulation(string name)
    {
        var capitol = GetCapitol(name);
        return capitol?.Population;
    }

    public Capitol GetCapitol(string name)
    {
        return capitols.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CapitolName.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim());
    }

    private static Lazy<SingleTOnDatabase> instance = new Lazy<SingleTOnDatabase>(() => new SingleTOnDatabase());
    public static SingleTOnDatabase Instance => instance.Value;

}
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var db = SingleTOnDatabase.Instance;
        var city = "Den Haag";
        var Country = "Nederland";
        Console.WriteLine($"{Country} with {city} has population of: {db.GetPopulation(city)}");

        var city2 = "Tokyo";
        var cap = db.GetCapitol(city2);
        if (cap == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unknown city [{city2}].");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{cap.CapitolName} is the capital of {cap.Country} and has population of: {cap.Population}");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

*Note: With your given sample text at top, this is the output I get:*

```
Initializing database
Nederland with Den Haag has population of: 787875454
Tokyo is the capital of Japan and has population of: 8797987
```

Comment: ah, thank you. oke, but do you also get an out of range exception?

Comment: @SavantKingOrange, No, why would I get that? (if you are using a text file as a database you should already have strict rules like having multiples of 3 lines).

Comment: Of course I don't store  it in a database. But It is for using the Batch command

Comment: I get this error: An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Singleton_app.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @SavantKingOrange, are you using the exact same text you gave as sample at top? I didn't include a check if the input file was faulty.

Comment: Tokyo 
Japan
8797987
Amsterdam
Nederland
88788787
Den Haag 
Nederland      
787875454
Madrid
Spain
7877878

Comment: @SavantKingOrange, then you wouldn't have an error but appearantly you have more than that (probably an empty line at the end). Anyway adding a guard against it, check the edited code.

Comment: @SavantKingOrange, I didn't understand your comment "Of course I don't store it in a database". What I am saying you should use a real database rather than a text file.

Comment: What I mean with that is that I am using the text file just for testing.